# how do i intall hadoop and hive on my windows 64 bit machine ? i am a beginner and a little naive about it. please enlighten

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to learn to install `hadoop` and hive on my machine . `windows 64 bit` os. please tell me the exact steps. it would help a lot for beginners like me. i tried and downloaded a `hadoop (1.1.1) version` but unable to install it.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to install on a Windows 64-bit on not on a Linux machine? You can easily use one of the VM from Cloudera, HortonWorks, MapR.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the developer preview of Microsoft HDInsight Server for Windows. Beware, it is a developer preview and a lot of features available on the native platform are not there yet. Most importantly HBase, in my opinion. But there is Hive, Pig and obviously the possibility to run standard MapReduce jobs. It's fun to play with.

[HDInsight Server Download Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35397)

There also is a .NET SDK to play with. This one is in pre-release phase and very undocumented but with some knowledge and some Google skills you should be able to manage it.

[SDK](http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/)